# Payment button is not rendering in next 12 from Snap Finance sdk

Tags: reactjs, next.js

hey guys please help me out, I am struggling from past 3 days to sort out this issue.
I have created /test page in next js and created a function called RenderButton.

```
const RenderButton = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('button gets called')
    const win = window as any;
    console.log(win)
    if (win.snapuk) {
      const clientId = "cfB9gZpXGM0HkhwVMtfyaD0m";
      win.snapuk.init(clientId);
      console.log('Clent Inititated')
      win.snapuk.checkout.button({
        transaction: transaction,
        merchantId: clientId,
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

and executing this RenderButton function with onClicking button.

```
<div>
      <Script
          src="https://sandbox-sdk.snapfinance.co.uk/v1/snapuk.min.js"
        />
      <h1>Hello</h1>
     
      <div id="snap-uk-checkout"></div>
      <button onClick={()=>RenderButton()}>Pay Now</button>
    </div>
```

the div with snap-uk-checkout with hold the payment button as per docs. but I am unable to see anything.
here is the doc link- https://qa3-developer.snapfinance.co.uk/sdks/javascript/
when I just copy paste their doc example in simple html file than it works perfectly, but dont know what happen in next js.

The sandbox link with normal html which is working fine. you guys can have a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-firefly-qkykqf?file=/index.html

Comment: You better provide a minimal runnable demo of your code on `codesanbox`, which can help debug more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the below code is written in next js for your issue, it is working correctly, make a file named 'test.js' and place the below code in it. Then, import the  component in wherever you want to place it.

```
`use client`;
import Script from "next/script";
import React from "react";

export default function Test() {
const initializeCheckoutButton = () => {
const clientId = "cfB9gZpXGM0HkhwVMtfyaD0m60";
const merchantId = "<!-- PLEASE ADD merchantId HERE -->";
if (window.snapuk) {
  window.snapuk.init(clientId);

  const transaction = {
    invoiceNumber: 51174155,
    deliveryDate: "2023-11-05",
    shippingCost: 50,
    customer: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Smith",
      email: "johnsmith@snapfinance.co.uk",
      mobileNumber: "07712345678",
      streetAddress: "The Quays",
      city: "Manchester",
      postcode: "M50 3BE",
      houseName: "",
      houseNumber: "7",
      unit: "Flat 165",
    },
    products: [
      {
        quantity: 2,
        productId: "iphone",
        price: 500.1,
        description: "Apple iPhone 11 Pro 256GB",
      },
    ],
  };

  window.snapuk.checkout.button({
    merchantId: merchantId,
    transaction: transaction,
    onClick: () => {
      console.log("Yay, the application loaded.");
    },
    onClose: (applicationId) => {
      console.log("Closed", applicationId ? applicationId : "");
    },
    onSuccess: (applicationId) => {
      console.log("Success", applicationId ? applicationId : "");
    },
    onError: (applicationId) => {
      console.log(
        "Something went wrong",
        applicationId ? applicationId : ""
      );
    },
    onDenied: (applicationId) => {
      console.log("Denied", applicationId ? applicationId : "");
    },
    onUnverifiedAccount: (applicationId) => {
      console.log("Account unverified", applicationId ? applicationId : "");
    },
    onPaymentFailure: (applicationId) => {
      console.log("Payment failure", applicationId ? applicationId : "");
    },
    onWithdrawn: (applicationId) => {
      console.log("Withdrawn", applicationId ? applicationId : "");
    },
  });
}
};

return (
<div>
  <Script
    defer
    src="https://sandbox-sdk.snapfinance.co.uk/v1/snapuk.min.js"
    onLoad={(result) => {
      console.log("onLoad", result);
      initializeCheckoutButton();
    }}
  />
  <h1>Hello</h1>

  <div id="snap-uk-checkout"></div>
</div>
);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: no success mam, same thing but in console I am getting the data.

Comment: Can you please share the error you're facing? and also share the code if its possible

Comment: mam is it because I am using typescript? cause when I run the same code in code sandbox than its working fine.

Comment: and Mam I am not getting an error that's the issue. Initially when I imported the test component which you gave me, then It show the payment button but when I refresh the page it again gone.

Comment: please share the code, I have to look as I have tried it on codesandbox as well as on my local, it's working fine even when refreshing the page.

Comment: mam unable to past code here don't know why. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-paper-qfr25m?file=/pages/index.js
mam here I replicate the code which I am using in my app inside pages/day/index.js but in my app its test.tsx

Comment: @nehatkhan, Below are the changes you need to do pages/index.js in codesandbox you shared above:
I am sharing code in the next comment.

Comment: `import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";`

`// import PerPageLayout from "layout/perpage";`

`import Script from "next/script";`
`import PaymentTest from "../components/Test";`

`const Test = () => {`
  `return (`
   `<div>`
     `<h1>Hello</h1>`
    `<PaymentTest />`
    `</div>`
`  );`
`};`
`export default Test;`